# Content moving in PageViewController tutorial slides

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipageviewcontroller, autoresizingmask

I'm using StoryBoards and have a PageViewController for my app tutorial screens.

All viewcontroller's on the storyboard are basically the same, except for a different image of course.  When it's running... the first view shows the image anchored to the bottom instead of centering in the view.

As soon as I start sliding to the left, it jumps up to where it should be.  All other subsequent views are working great.  The second screen grab shows what happens after I start sliding to the next screen.

I'm stumped, I've never seen this before.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets is set to false in your container.